# how EJB Life cycle methods are invoked

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb-2.x

Can some one explain on how typical sessin bean's life cycle is and who hadle those?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the best if you look at the manual of sun. The ejb component will take care of that for you
[EJB Life Cycle](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/EJBConcepts9.html)